# Use php and js functions in 'items wrap'

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

How can i use php functions and js functions when im changing 'items_wrap' and im already inside php code? 
When i click on Home "echo%20get_home_url();" gets added to the URL and myFunction doesnt run at all.

```
<?php
    wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'primary' ,
    'items_wrap' => 
    '<ul class="topnav">
    <li class="home" id="home"><a href="echo get_home_url();">Home</a>
    %3$s
    <li class="icon">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
    </li>
    </ul>'
    ));
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to concatenate the value. If a string starts with double quotes `"`, php variable can be declare as `{$variable}`. With single quotes, though, you have to make a full stop, add a `.` the value and restore the single quote if more value is needed.

That said:

```
<?php
    wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'primary' ,
    'items_wrap' =>  '<ul class="topnav">
                          <li class="home" id="home">
                             <a href="' . get_home_url() . '">Home</a>%3$s
                          </li>
                          <li class="icon">
                             <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
                          </li>
                      </ul>'
    ));
?>
```

Also, you forgot to close the `li.home` tag.